# cStringIO to django FileField or ImageField

Tags: django, filefield, imagefield

I'm trying to save image using cStringio through django FileField.

I tried **File** and **ContentFile**
Also I tried to switch from **FileField** to **ImageField**

The file always flushes on the disk  with the same size(greater than original image), **but the image seems to be broken, it not opens**.
Is there any way to implement that?

```
 from django.core.files import File
 from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
 import cStringIO

 class Captcha(models.Model):
     path_var = 'captchas'
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_var, blank=True, max_length=100)

 fl = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
 output = cStringIO.StringIO(fl.read())

 myfile = ContentFile(output)

 cap = Captcha()
 cap.image.save('anyname.jpg', content=myfile)
```

**upd:** I found the solution after 2 hrs without luck. I just tried to open anyname.jpg with text editor, and I have seen text ""
so it must be

```
myfile = ContentFile(output.read())
```

Comment: I found the solution after 2 hrs without luck. I just tried to open anyname.jpg with text editor, and I have seen text "<cStringIO.StringI object at 0x7ff4afcc3e00>"
so it must be  
myfile = ContentFile(output.read())